# Is it possible to authenticate a Microsoft login through Firebase in a React Native Expo app?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory, expo

I am trying to create a Login authentication with Microsoft using Firebase and Azure Active Directory.

Is there a support for Expo?

Comment: One of the easiest way to do it is just by grabbing the MSFT email on successful login from your MSFT login flow and then using email/pass auth on Firebase side. Initially, for signup, you can generate a random password for user and for login, you will just match the email.

Comment: Hello @gchan26 , If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be possible to authenticate Microsoft Azure AD login through the Firebase in React Native application.

To sign in users using Microsoft accounts (Azure Active Directory and personal Microsoft accounts), you must first enable Microsoft as a sign-in provider for your Firebase project:

Would suggest you follow the steps given in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth) .

You Can also refer this document for more clarification : https://medium.com/seed-digital/using-microsoft-azure-identity-with-firebase-in-a-react-native-app-c9eef0fd0af8