# React Native Expo with Firebase Authenticate Microsoft error

Tags: azure, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, signing

I'm doing socials login with firebase (facebook and google is ok) but have problem with microsoft

I used `expo-auth-session` to get the `response.params.code` from Azure and then use `exchangeCodeAsync` to get the `idToken` + `accessToken`

Next I use `signInWithCredential` as shown below but get wrong providerId or credential error
If anyone has encountered this problem, please help me

[sign with credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXeSs.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use react-native-firebase/auth OAuth provider to auth Azure AD credential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989490/use-react-native-firebase-auth-oauth-provider-to-auth-azure-ad-credential)

Comment: [Is it possible to authenticate a Microsoft login through Firebase in a React Native Expo app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499854/is-it-possible-to-authenticate-a-microsoft-login-through-firebase-in-a-react-nat) and [Authenticate Using Microsoft with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth)